# auth.signOut() or signOut(auth). Is there any difference or major advantage with any of them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Is there any difference or major advantage with using `auth.signOut()` or `signOut(auth)` of them?
This principle for sure also affects the same pattern for logging in, signing up, and so on.
The [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#web-version-9) (Web9) only uses the approach with functions `signOut(auth)`. But most articles or tutorials using `auth.signOut()`.
I guess it's a very basic question but I've seen everyone approaching it differently so I'm glad to solve this in the best way possible.

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app;
```

**Auth1.js**

```
import { auth } from "./firebase.js";

// Option 1
function logout() {
  return auth.signOut();
}
```

**Auth2.js**

```
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "./firebase.js";

// Option 2
function logout() {
  return signOut(auth);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .js firebase SDK has a version 9 with is a major refacto to lighten the lib and bring a lot of new features (tree-sharing for eg).

`auth.signOut` is version 8, [doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth?hl=en#signout)
`signOut(auth)` is version 9, [doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signout)

Comment: In addition to that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#modular-version) a link to the differences.